# Call a 86x Dll from Java

Tags: java, visual-c++, dll, x86

Am trying to call a x86 DLL that I created using VC 6, from a java project on Eclipse, first try I got an error saying that I can't call a x86 DLL from a x64 envirement and that the DLL can't be loaded. So I installed a x86 jre and I have no more problem to charge the DLL. 
But when I try to call my c++ function I get the following exception:

```
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: mm.SimpleDLL.SimpleDLL_Calculation_Add(II)I
```

Can someone please help me ?
Thank you.

SimpleDLL.h

```
    #ifndef SIMPLE_DLL_H
    #define SIMPLE_DLL_H

    namespace SimpleDll
    {

    extern class Calculation
    {
    public:
     static __declspec(dllexport) int Add(int a, int b);
    };
    }

    #endif SIMPLE_DLL_H
```

SimpleDLL.cpp

```
    #include "SimpleDll.h"

    namespace SimpleDll
    {

       int Calculation::Add(int a, int b)
      { return a + b; }

    }
```

SimpleDLL.java

```
    package mm;

    public class SimpleDLL {

        static
        {
            System.load("D:\\SimpleDLL.dll");   
        }
        public static void main(String ar[])
        {
            System.out.println("Hello world from Java");
            SimpleDLL t=new SimpleDLL();
            int x = t.SimpleDLL_Calculation_Add(6, 7);
            System.out.println("Resultat  "+x);
        }
        public native int SimpleDLL_Calculation_Add(int a, int b);
    }
```

**[Exported DLL Functions View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcXbH.png)**

Resolved using the JNA library, I used this **[link](https://shansvex.wordpress.com/2013/05/23/using-a-dll-in-java-with-jna-java-native-access/)** to walkthrough

Comment: Finally it worked for me using the JNA library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build a 32-bit DLL and a `.h` file using `javah` for the exact signature Java expects. It is usually something like

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_Sample1_booleanMethod
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jboolean);
```

from https://medium.com/@bschlining/a-simple-java-native-interface-jni-example-in-java-and-scala-68fdafe76f5f

An alternative approach is to use a library like JNA or JNR-FFI which allow you to bind to a C library without writing this bridging code.

Comment: Hello Peter, and thank you for your reply, could you please tell me what is wrong with my approch ? is it not working beacause it's a 32-bit DLL on a 64-bit JVM or simply because it's no more working like that for java 8... ?

Comment: @FeridRaouf A 64-bit process can only load 64bit DLLs, a 32-bit process can only load 32-bit DLL. This is a limitation of the OS. You can't name your method just anything you like, you have to give it a specific name in C as generated by `javah` which in turn can call your C++ code.

Comment: I tryed to use the JNA library and I created the same DLL example you linked but I can't get the code see the DLL function:     
      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'Add': La procédure spécifiée est introuvable.

Comment: @FeridRaouf you have to use the method name as it would appear to a C program, rather than a C++ program.